# Add support for embedding "youtu.be" links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Youtube launched a site-specific URL shortening service (youtu.be) about a year ago, but we currently only support full URL.  Can we get support added for the shortened ones?  They can even be directly converted to long URLs:

[image: URL comparison with highlights]

[Relevant question which attempted to use short URLs.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/38867/revisions)

Comment: Also very helpful if you're uploading videos yourself.  The link YouTube gives back to use uses the shortened url.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shortened links will work after the next build.

Keep in mind this doesn't affect *exisiting* posts, as the replacement is done at he time of the edit as part of the markdown -> HTML cook, only new or edited posts will get the embed love for the shortened link version.